# Bash/ Take substring from a string

Tags: bash, sh

I run the next:

```
 find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1
```

this return me the next:

```
1376221215.000000000 ./Rev.12345/run.exe
```

I want to get only the 12345 number. Which command I should use (I try to use cut command, without success)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pipe the output to `sed`:

```
... | sed 's/.*Rev\.\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe the output with:

```
awk -F '[./]+' '{print $4}'
```

Answer (score 1):

U can use grep also

```
... | grep -o Rev.[0-9]* s | grep -o [0-9]*
```